# New to jQuery Gallery Development

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm extremely new to jQuery.  I'm attempting to build my own photo gallery with a hidden image that only appears once you've clicked on one the smaller images.  I'm not completely sure why this doesn't work.  Like I said I'm very new to jQuery and this feels like a very complicated goal.  Any help with tightening up the code would be appreciated.  Would really like to get this thing functional.

```
function gallery()  //displays only the first l2 photos in the database.  fix it when i figure a workaround for printing all of the thumbnails.
{
try
{
    $album_id = $_GET['id'] ;
    $db = honneyconnect( ) ;
    if( mysqli_connect_error() )
    {
        throw new Exception( "Could not connect to the database") ;
    }
    $query = 'select * from albums where album_id="'.$album_id.'"' ;
    $albums = $db->query( $query) ;
    $album_name = $albums->fetch_row();
    $default_pic = $album_name[1].'/'.$album_name[2] ;
    $albums->free();
    $query = 'select * from photos where album_id="'.$album_id.'"' ;
    $photos = $db->query( $query ) ;
    if( !$photos )
    {
        throw new Exception( "Query returned zero results." ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        $number_of_photos = $photos->num_rows ;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> array_size = parseInt( ".$number_of_photos." ) ;</script>" ; //figure out the size of the javascript array of photo sources 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var picture_list = new Array( array_size ) ;</script>" ; //define the array
        echo "<div id='gallery'>" ;
        echo "<img id='largeImage' src='".$default_pic."' >";
        echo "<div id='thumbpanel'>" ;

        if( $number_of_photos > 12 )
        {
            $stop = 12 ;
        }
        else
        {
            $stop = $number_of_photos ;
        }
        for( $i = 0; $i < 12 ; $i++ )
        {
            $row = $photos->fetch_row() ;
            if( !$row )
            {
                $i = 12 ;
            }
            else
            {
                $file_path = $album_name[1]."/".$row[2] ; //provides the path for the image source
                echo "<img value='".$i."' src='".$file_path."'>" ; //assigns the value for use in the jQuery scripts
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> picture_list[ parseInt( ".$i.") ] = ".$file_path."</script>" ;  //sends the values to the jQuery script
            }
        }
        echo "</div></div>" ;
    }
        $photos->free();
        $db->close();
}
catch( Exception $error )
{
    echo $error ;
}
}
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @import "honeysstyle.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
var array_size = 0 ;
var active_index ;
$('#largeImage').hide() ;
$('#gallery img').click(function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('gallery','large'));
    $('#largeImage').show() ;
    active_index = parseInt( $(this).attr('value') ) ;

});
$('.next').click(function(){
    active_index = active_index + 1 ;
    if( active_index >= array_size )
    {
        $(this).hide() ;
    }
    if( active_index > 0 )
    {
        $('.back').show() ;
    }
    var source_image = $('#largeImage').attr('src') ;
    $('#largeImage').attr('src').replace( source_image, picture_list[ active_index ] ) ;


});
$('.back').click(function(){
    active_index = active_index - 1 ;
    if( active_index <= 0 )
    {
        $(this).hide() ;
    }
    if( active_index < array_size )
    {
        $('.next').show() ;
    }
    var source_image = $('#largeImage').attr('src') ;
    $('#largeImage').attr('src').replace( source_image, picture_list[ active_index ] ) ;

}) ;
$('.close').click(function{
    $('#largeImage').hide() ;
}) ;



});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require( 'function.php' );

draw_masthead();
gallery();



?>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently all the images get drawn but none of the jQuery works and I'm not sure why.  There are no issues with the php code.
This outputs the following html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import "honeysstyle.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
var array_size = 0 ;
var active_index ;
$('#largeImage').hide() ;
$('#gallery img').click(function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('gallery','large'));
    $('#largeImage').show() ;
    active_index = parseInt( $(this).attr('value') ) ;

});
$('.next').click(function(){
    active_index = active_index + 1 ;
    if( active_index >= array_size )
    {
        $(this).hide() ;
    }
    if( active_index > 0 )
    {
        $('.back').show() ;
    }
    var source_image = $('#largeImage').attr('src') ;
    $('#largeImage').attr('src').replace( source_image, picture_list[ active_index ] ) ;


});
$('.back').click(function(){
    active_index = active_index - 1 ;
    if( active_index <= 0 )
    {
        $(this).hide() ;
    }
    if( active_index < array_size )
    {
        $('.next').show() ;
    }
    var source_image = $('#largeImage').attr('src') ;
    $('#largeImage').attr('src').replace( source_image, picture_list[ active_index ] ) ;

}) ;
$('.close').click(function{
    $('#largeImage').hide() ;
}) ;



});
</script>
</head>
<body>




<div id="container">
<div class="photobanner">
    <img class="first" src="honeys/Image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image5.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="honeys/Image4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div><div id="titlebar">HELL'S CANYON HONEYS ROLLER DERBY</div>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="news.php">News</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Events</a>
    <ul class="eventnav">
        <li><a href="community.php">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="bouts.php">Bouts</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">The Team</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="roster.php">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="albums.php">Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="sponsors.php">Sponsors</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="social.php">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div id="controlpanel">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="rosteredit.php">Edit Roster</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="albums.php">Edit Albums</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="editevents.php">Edit Events</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="editnews.php">Edit News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="editsponsors.php">Edit Sponsors</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="editcontact.php">Edit Contact Info</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="clearsession.php">Log Out</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div><script type='text/javascript'> array_size = parseInt( 4 ) ;</script>    <script type='text/javascript'> var picture_list = new Array( array_size ) ;</script><div id='gallery'><img id='largeImage' src='rosterpics/Image3.jpg' ><div id='thumbpanel'><img value='0' src='rosterpics/image2.jpg'><script type='text/javascript'> picture_list[ parseInt( 0) ] = rosterpics/image2.jpg</script><img value='1' src='rosterpics/Image3.jpg'><script type='text/javascript'> picture_list[ parseInt( 1) ] = rosterpics/Image3.jpg</script><img value='2' src='rosterpics/Image4.jpg'><script type='text/javascript'> picture_list[ parseInt( 2) ] = rosterpics/Image4.jpg</script><img value='3' src='rosterpics/Image5.jpg'><script type='text/javascript'> picture_list[ parseInt( 3) ] = rosterpics/Image5.jpg</script></div></div></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what doesn't work? Is it your php `gallery()` function not building your gallery? Is it your jQuery is not switching between the images? Right now it is a code dump, which makes it difficult for us to help. Can you show the output code, or recreate using http://jsFiddle.net. One small change would be to change `for( $i = 0; $i < 12 ; $i++ ){$row = $photos->fetch_row(); if( !$row ) { $i = 12; } ...` to `for( $i = 0; $i < $stop ; $i++ ){$row = $photos->fetch_row(); if( !$row ) { $i = $stop; } ...`

Comment: I just updated it.  Sorry for the lack of info to begin with.  No php issues just none of the jQuery works.

Comment: Can you post a simplified html output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you've given,it appears that you have made a mistake here:

```
 $('.close').click(function{
      $('#largeImage').hide() ;
 }) ;
```

Change this to :

```
  $('.close').click(function(){
      $('#largeImage').hide() ;
 }) ;
```

For further help,tell us more about your html.

You could use the Developer console in your browser(Press F12) and tell us if you've got any error.

[image]

Comment: After looking through the developer's console there don't appear to be any errors that I can notice.  I've updated the original post with the html that is out put for easier viewing.  I'm not sure that I need the parseInt() function.  I'm essentially at this point just trying to hide the #largeImage from the initial load and then show it and change the src of that image to one of the smaller thumbnails.  I haven't added the back, next, or close buttons as I feel that if I can get the core functionality to run I can probably get the rest of it figured out.

Comment: At line 129(in your html),I think you should change this:picture_list[ parseInt( 0) ] = rosterpics/image2.jpg to picture_list[ parseInt( 0) ] = 'rosterpics/image2.jpg'

Comment: This fixed the issue of the jQuery not working at all.  However, now that I've added the .next and .back buttons they just hide the image again.  Am I setting the values of the javascript array correctly?  Should I remove the parseInt() function from the numerical values?